# Why is my macro starting in row 1 instead of row 2?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure why my macro is starting this =TRIM(F2) formula in cell E1 instead of E2.

```
'Insert TRIM Contract Column & formula
    Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="Contract", After:=Cells(1, 1))
    rngUsernameHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("E1").Value = "TRIM CONTRACT"
    Range("E1").Font.Bold = True
    Range("E2").Select

 Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("E2:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E2:E" & lastRow) = _
        "=TRIM(F2)"
    Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Select
    Range("E2:E" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
```

I'm just trying to insert a column (column E) that contains the TRIM values in the column next to it (column F, aka 'Contract')

Comment: `lastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` or you probably actually want: `lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I also removed all unnecessary lines:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro3()
'Insert TRIM Contract Column & formula
    Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="Contract", After:=Cells(1, 1))
    rngUsernameHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("E1").Value = "TRIM CONTRACT"
    Range("E1").Font.Bold = True

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E2:E" & lastRow) = "=TRIM(F2)"
End Sub
```

Cheers .

---

**Followup:**
If you don't know what column is going to contain "Contract" you need to make all further cell references related to your found cell:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Insert_Formula_Found_Column()
'Insert TRIM Contract Column & formula

    Dim RngHeaders As Range
    Dim RngUserNameHeader As Range
    Dim BuiltFormula As String
    
    Set RngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row
    Set RngUserNameHeader = RngHeaders.Find(what:="Contract", After:=Cells(1, 1))
    
    RngUserNameHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
    RngUserNameHeader.Offset(0, -1).Value = "TRIM CONTRACT"
    RngUserNameHeader.Offset(0, -1).Font.Bold = True

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = RngUserNameHeader.Offset(Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    BuiltFormula = "=TRIM(" & Replace(RngUserNameHeader.Offset(1, 0).Address, "$", "") & ")"
    RngUserNameHeader.Offset(1, -1).Resize(lastRow).Formula = BuiltFormula
    
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your assistance; however & unfortunately, it is still putting the formula in row 1 :( Could it be because the top row is frozen?

Comment: I changed `lastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to `lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` as that's where your source data will be.

Comment: What's the point of searching `.Find` for "Contract" if you know it will always be in Column E? On the other hand, if I might be in different locations, you'll need to edit your code to move with that column.

Comment: I'm not sure 'Contract' will always be in Column E, which is why I tried to write that to find it. What you wrote works now; before, I had left out the 'Option Explicit'. Once I added 'Option Explicit', it started working correctly -- rookie mistake (smh in shame). Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay so see above edit, the first code we wrote isn't going to work if "Contact" column moves.